# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow==2.7.0

Tags: python, pip, cloud-foundry, python-imaging-library

I have a requirements.txt file with the line below

```
Pillow==2.7.0
```

I download the requirements for offline mode like this and put it in vendor director

```
pip install --download vendor -r requirements.txt
```

This downloads the file `Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel` to my `vendor` directory

But when I try to deploy (push) my app I get the error below:

```
   Collecting Pillow==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))   
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: ) 
No matching distribution found for Pillow==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
```

I am deploying the app to Cloud Foundry using the Python Buildpack following this documentation http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring

Comment: It seems to be downloading the Intel MacOS 10.9 version of the package, which is unlikely to be the same system as you're running CloudFoundry on.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just saw your comment, was surprised by the same things.  Seems an odd approach for deploying.

Comment: I'd hit up the cloud foundry support/help, this can't be the first time they've seen anything like this with the approach they're taking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Another post points out how you can specify to recent versions of pip a flag not to pull binaries (which I'm assuming is the issue).  If that resolves the issues then you should pick his post as solution.  I'd also poke cloudfoundry just needing to point this out.

The `--download` option just downloads the file for the dependency, but not actually install it (that might have contributed to why the flag was deprecated, to get rid of this confusion).

> pip download replaces the --download option to pip install, which is now deprecated and will be removed in pip 10.

It's the same as the newer:

```
pip  download ....
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/

Now assuming your cloud provider is reading the requirements.txt and looking themselves in your vendor folder to install (a-not-so-wise-approach), you'd potentially have all kinds of issues with any binaries, symbolic links, etc... unless the environment you're deploying to matches the local environment.  Part of the idea with package systems like pip and a requirements file is so different platforms can pull down the needed libraries for their specific architecture, OS, etc...

This approach has so many things could go wrong...

For example, your mac probably is using a case insensitive file system.  If the cloudfoundry is using linux, that's case-sensitive.  On mac, this wouldn't matter if they saved it all lower case, but might be an issue when copying the files to a linux system expecting to match a capitlized "P".

Comment: I understand that. I am referring to this http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring

Comment: @Anthony I see.  So you don't want them to install, the service you're using will.  Odd setup as to do this as the local version your pip pulls won't match the remote deploy

Comment: Assuming it's more than just code, but binaries and such

Comment: @Anthony *I understand that.* – how did this answer help you solve the problem then?

Answer (score 1):

In example at http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring you can see the following comment

> vendors all the pip *.tar.gz into vendor/

`*.tar.gz` packages are source packages whereas recent versions of pip download binary packages by default. To force pip to download **only** source packages use `--no-binary :all:` If you want to download binary packages you have to specify target platform as per this remark from `pip download` [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/?highlight=binary#pip-download):

> `pip download` with the `--platform`, `--python-version`,
>   `--implementation`, and `--abi` options provides the ability to fetch
>   dependencies for an interpreter and system other than the ones that
>   pip is running on. `--only-binary=:all:` is required when using any of
>   these options. It is important to note that these options all default
>   to the current system/interpreter, and not to the most restrictive
>   constraints (e.g. platform any, abi none, etc). To avoid fetching
>   dependencies that happen to match the constraint of the current
>   interpreter (but not your target one), it is recommended to specify
>   all of these options if you are specifying one of them.

Comment: Ah, figures since they've not updated the doc's to use the newer `pip download`  syntax this was missed.  He should try this and it will factor out any issue with binaries / local system